# Customizing File Paths in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, electron, jsx, electron-builder

The default path I receive is "/_next/static/css/650b9dca11a5e4cf.css", but during build time, I prefer the path to start with "_next" instead of "/" in order to access the file in Electron.

Next Config :

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output : 'export',
    basePath: '',
};

export default nextConfig;
```

package.json

```json
"homepage": ""
```